# How do I bind data for autocomple to input fields in materialize?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, materialize

I'm using materialize framework for a personal project and following the documentation I was able to add the data to autocomplete my form fields.

In this form, the user will fill in data about his vehicle.

```
  $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
         "Verde": null,
         "Rojo": null,
         "Azul": null,
         "Honda": null,
         "Toyota": null,
},
limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
onAutocomplete: function(val) {
  // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
},
minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
```

However, while filling in data about the vehicle brand, the autocomplete will suggest "rojo". How do I separate data from specific fields?

Comment: explain what do you mean by `How do I separate data from specific fields?`

Comment: I mean, I want that Honda and Toyota suggestions only appear for input Brand. And Verde, rojo and azul only for input color.

Comment: You're putting all in same data object that means any input box having class autocomplete will have to suggest all that pre-defined data, no meter its vehicle or whatever( browser doesn't have intelligence to understand that its a vehicle). To solve this, you should declare two different autocomplete for two different purposes. suppose one for vehicle class and one for color class, which will have different dataset. `$('input.vehicle').autocomplete({ /* data for vehicle */ })` and `$('input.color').autocomplete({ /* data for color */ })`

Comment: I did think of something like that. But materialize documentation states that I should add class autocomplete to my input tag. How do I bind each input to each autocomplete I declare? Sorry, maybe it's too dumb to ask but I got no experience with jquery.

Comment: no meter what kind of class you use. `$('.any').autocomplete({ });` will definitely work. It means we are binding autocomplete with given options to specific selector, No meter what selector it is